# Adding new tab in between Account Information and Address Book in account dashboard

Tags: magento-2.2.5

[image]I want to display some information in account dashboard. How to override default one with new one

I want a tab similar to the one highlighted in yellow box(with custom content like User Name, Dob, etc) to be displayed between the 'Account Information' block and 'Address Block'(where the red arrow is pointing).

Comment: Can share a screesnshot  where you want to add ?

Comment: Shared the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Manage from Custom module

If you want to changes the section from a custom module then

1. create `customer_account_index.xml` at `app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout`
2. create a template `mycustominfo.phtml`  at `app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/templates`

Now, you add below code at  `customer_account_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" 
            name="customer_account_dashboard_mycustominfo" 
            as="mycustominfo"
            before ="customer_account_dashboard_info"   
        template="{Vendor}_{Module}::mycustominfo.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

### Manage from Theme module

If you want to changes the section from a custom theme then

1. create `customer_account_index.xml`  id not exits at `app/design/{VendorTheme}/{ThemeName}/Magento_Customer/layout`
2. create a template `mycustominfo.phtml`  at `app/design/{VendorTheme}/{ThemeName}/Magento_Customer/templates`

Now, you add below code at  `customer_account_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" 
            name="customer_account_dashboard_mycustominfo" 
            as="mycustominfo"
            before ="customer_account_dashboard_info"   
        template="Magento_Customer::mycustominfo.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```